# How to configure podman to use volumes quota on XFS storage

Tags: podman

I want to set a quota to podman volumes (using an XFS storage mounted with *prjquota* option) so I configured as documented [here](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-volume-create.1.html#quotas):

```
root@odroid:~# cat /etc/projects 
100000:/storage/containers/graphroot/overlay
200000:/storage/containers/graphroot/volumes

root@odroid:~# cat /etc/projid 
storage:100000
volumes:200000
```

When I create the first volume it's all ok:

```
root@odroid:~# podman volume create --opt o=size=100M volume1
volume1

root@odroid:~# xfs_quota -x -c "report -a -h" /storage/containers
Project quota on /storage/containers (/dev/mapper/luks-73764eef-ecc9-4323-aadc-9940738aff36)
                        Blocks              
Project ID   Used   Soft   Hard Warn/Grace   
---------- --------------------------------- 
#0           128K      0      0  00 [------]
storage        4K      0      0  00 [------]
volumes         0      0      0  00 [------]
#200001         0  95.4M  95.4M  00 [------]
```

But when I create the second volume it does not create a second project id but only updates the quota of the first:

```
root@odroid:~# podman volume create --opt o=size=200M volume2
volume2
root@odroid:~# xfs_quota -x -c "report -a -h" /storage/containers
Project quota on /storage/containers (/dev/mapper/luks-73764eef-ecc9-4323-aadc-9940738aff36)
                        Blocks              
Project ID   Used   Soft   Hard Warn/Grace   
---------- --------------------------------- 
#0           128K      0      0  00 [------]
storage        4K      0      0  00 [------]
volumes         0      0      0  00 [------]
#200001         0 190.7M 190.7M  00 [------]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my podman configuration:

```
root@odroid:~# podman info
host:
  arch: arm64
  buildahVersion: 1.23.1
  cgroupControllers:
  - io
  - memory
  - pids
  cgroupManager: systemd
  cgroupVersion: v2
  conmon:
    package: 'conmon: /usr/bin/conmon'
    path: /usr/bin/conmon
    version: 'conmon version 2.0.25, commit: unknown'
  cpus: 4
  distribution:
    codename: jammy
    distribution: ubuntu
    version: "22.04"
  eventLogger: journald
  hostname: odroid
  idMappings:
    gidmap: null
    uidmap: null
  kernel: 4.9.337-13
  linkmode: dynamic
  logDriver: journald
  memFree: 2585001984
  memTotal: 3889238016
  ociRuntime:
    name: crun
    package: 'crun: /usr/bin/crun'
    path: /usr/bin/crun
    version: |-
      crun version 0.17
      commit: 0e9229ae34caaebcb86f1fde18de3acaf18c6d9a
      spec: 1.0.0
      +SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +YAJL
  os: linux
  remoteSocket:
    exists: true
    path: /run/podman/podman.sock
  security:
    apparmorEnabled: false
    capabilities: CAP_CHOWN,CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE,CAP_FOWNER,CAP_FSETID,CAP_KILL,CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE,CAP_SETFCAP,CAP_SETGID,CAP_SETPCAP,CAP_SETUID,CAP_SYS_CHROOT
    rootless: false
    seccompEnabled: true
    seccompProfilePath: /usr/share/containers/seccomp.json
    selinuxEnabled: false
  serviceIsRemote: false
  slirp4netns:
    executable: /usr/bin/slirp4netns
    package: 'slirp4netns: /usr/bin/slirp4netns'
    version: |-
      slirp4netns version 1.0.1
      commit: 6a7b16babc95b6a3056b33fb45b74a6f62262dd4
      libslirp: 4.6.1
  swapFree: 0
  swapTotal: 0
  uptime: 2h 4m 36.78s (Approximately 0.08 days)
plugins:
  log:
  - k8s-file
  - none
  - journald
  network:
  - bridge
  - macvlan
  volume:
  - local
registries: {}
store:
  configFile: /etc/containers/storage.conf
  containerStore:
    number: 0
    paused: 0
    running: 0
    stopped: 0
  graphDriverName: overlay
  graphOptions: {}
  graphRoot: /storage/containers/graphroot
  graphStatus:
    Backing Filesystem: xfs
    Native Overlay Diff: "true"
    Supports d_type: "true"
    Using metacopy: "false"
  imageStore:
    number: 0
  runRoot: /storage/containers/runroot
  volumePath: /storage/containers/graphroot/volumes
version:
  APIVersion: 3.4.4
  Built: 0
  BuiltTime: Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970
  GitCommit: ""
  GoVersion: go1.18.1
  OsArch: linux/arm64
  Version: 3.4.4
```

Comment: Maybe you found a bug? If you post the question at https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions I think you would increase the likelihood that the Podman development team read the question. The Podman version you are using ([3.4.4](https://github.com/containers/podman/releases/tag/v3.4.4)) is two years old. You could also test if it works with a recent Podman release.

Comment: I had already tried with podman 4.6.2. using the [Kubic packages](https://podman.io/docs/installation#ubuntu) but I got the same behavior.

Comment: See: https://github.com/containers/podman/discussions/21193